# Keeping the Holo Action Bar in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there any way to force an app to display the Holo Action Bar in Lollipop devices?

My theme is currently inheriting from Holo.Light, yet I am seeing the new Action Bar. The Youtube app does this but I believe that it is using an older version of the AppCompat library.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: New appcompat only does Material. The Holo theme is deprecated.

Comment: You have control over the new toolbar which you can theme it as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to force an app to display the Holo Action Bar in Lollipop devices?

Use `Theme.Holo` or one of its subsidiary themes, directly or as an inherited theme.

> My theme is currently inheriting from Holo.Light, yet I am seeing the new Action Bar

First, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ShareNative) that uses `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` directly in its manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```

The results when run on a Nexus 4 running Android 5.0 show the Holo-style action bar, even showing the now-deprecated split action bar pattern:

[image: ShareNative sample app, as initially run]

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/HoloColor) that refers to a custom theme:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme">
```

where that custom theme inherits from `Theme.Holo` and modifies the action bar, courtesy of Jeff Gilfelt's [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/):

```
<style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_apptheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Apptheme</item>
</style>
```

The results when run on a Nexus 4 running Android 5.0 show the styled action bar:

[image: HoloColor demo, as initially run]

If you can offer a reproducible test case that demonstrates a `Theme.Holo`-based app offering a Material-ish look (which is my interpretation of "the new Action Bar"), please upload it somewhere.

Comment: It was a silly styling error. I didn't notice a style inheriting from an incorrect parent in values-20/styles.xml :|

Comment: @CarlosPaulino: Whew. Your question scared me there for a while. :-)