# Changing Theme in Android Studio

Tags: android

I just noticed that the default theme when I am creating an android application in AS is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` which, for me, is very plain.

My question is how to use `Holo Light Theme`?

Because when I tried in giving me an error underlining the statement.

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)

Comment: you have to add 'android:' prefix

Comment: @AhmedZiani no this is not the same question as what youve link. I am not trying to change the AS theme itself. What I meant is the theme of my application.

Comment: The real question is, why you would like to use Holo Light Theme? And here's a possible way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389689/keeping-the-holo-action-bar-in-lollipop

Comment: Your question heading should be "Changing Application or Layout Theme" instead of "Changing Theme"..

Answer (score 0):

If you could show us what you're doing in your styles.xml file that isn't working it would be very helpful.

Otherwise, I think you're looking for something along the lines of `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">`. The key is that this is an android provided theme and is found using `android:Theme`